# Restructing a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, python, bash, csv

I have basic scripting knowledge but I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I am trying to convert my banks automatically generated CSV file into a format that YNAB (You Need a Budget) can understand.

**YNAB Format (desired format of csv file)**

```
Date,Payee,Category,Memo,Outflow,Inflow
07/25/10,Sample Payee,,Sample Memo for an outflow,100.00,
07/26/10,Sample Payee 2,,Sample memo for an inflow,,500.00
```

**Bank Format (current state of csv file)**

```
"Account Type","Account Number","Transaction Date","Cheque Number","Description 1","Description 2","CAD$","USD$"
Chequing,00401-1234567,8/19/2013,,"Transfer","WWW TRANSFER - 0645 ",50.00,,
Chequing,00401-1234567,8/19/2013,,"STARBUCKS AC. U","IDP PURCHASE - 6678 ",-1.94,,
```

(all fake data)

What can I do to transform my current CSV file into the format desired?

Comment: Since you added the `python` tag, perhaps you're considering writing a script in python? That sounds like a good starting point. Try to write something and when you get stuck come back with a specific question.

Comment: [tag:awk] could do this quite easily.

Comment: I would strongly recommend `python` over `awk`. The latter has rather steep learning curve, and quite narrow field, whereas python knowledge would serve author in much more broad experiences.

Comment: I don't feel like learning a new language just to split two numbers. My goal changed: Where there is a negative number for "CAD$", make all positives go into category "Inflow" and all negative numbers into category "Outflow".

Comment: `awk` cannot easily handle the case where a quoted field contains a comma, as it will not distinguish such a comma from a field delimiter.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I like to do that in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
import csv
import sys

if sys.hexversion >= 0x3000000:
    inp = input
else:
    inp = raw_input

def main():
    input_file  = inp('Name of bank statement file? ')
    output_file = inp('Save YNAB output file as? ')

    with open(input_file, 'rb') as inf, open(output_file, 'wb') as outf:
        incsv  = csv.reader(inf)
        outcsv = csv.write(outf)
        # deal with headers
        header = next(incsv)
        outcsv.write(['Date', 'Payee', 'Category', 'Memo', 'Outflow', 'Inflow'])
        # translate data
        for row in incsv:
            cad = float(row[6])
            ynab = [row[2], row[4], '', row[5], -cad if cad < 0. else '', cad if cad > 0. else '']
            outcsv.writerow(ynab)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

I strongly encourage you to raise (or even start) your python scrpiting skills at this task.

First learn how to read the file and split it into parts (list of lists). 
Then practice in printing values, then print entire output lines (with properly reordered values).

Then sprinkle in some sorting logic, so that you output various lines upon conditions desired.

Comment: Once I finish this contract job I plan to learn everything under the sun! :)